# Hide "Gallery Settings" and "Insert into Post" button from Attachment window

Tags: attachments, gallery

I'm using different method to form a gallery in Wordpress, so I would like to hide an option to insert images and galleries into post for anyone but Administrator.

Can someone show me an example how it's done?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you actually wanted to remove it instead of just hiding it you could remove the 'admin-gallery' script that is used to insert the gallery settings form. And if you wanted it to be remove only for non-admins then something like this should work:

```
function disable_wp_gallery()
{
    if( !current_user_can('manage_options') )
        wp_deregister_script('admin-gallery');
}
add_action('admin_enqueue_scripts', 'disable_wp_gallery');
```

Answer (score 1):

To remove elements in the media editor, you can *unset* them. I haven't tested it for the insert button, but you can try this. Put this function in the `functions.php` file of your theme.

```
function remove_media_editor_fields($fields) {
  unset($fields['submit']);
  return $fields;
}
add_filter('attachment_fields_to_edit','remove_media_editor_fields');
```

Or with CSS, for both elements you cite :

```
function add_custom_admin_styles() {

    if( !current_user_can('administrator') ){
        echo '
        <style type="text/css">
            #media-items #savesend .button{display:none!important;}
                 #gallery-settings{display:none!important;}
        </style>';
    }

}
```

Comment: It doesn't work and even if it did, I believe it would remove all buttons (thumbnail and delete).
As for Gallery Options, that's what I did, but I thought there's better way to do it :)

Comment: I uptaded the example with a CSS fix to hide the insert button only, and the gallery settings, sorry I don't know any other way than add CSS to hide those elements.

Answer (score 0):

Well, I couldn't find how to `unset` it, so I'm using my old method:

```
function auto_media() {
    echo '<style type="text/css">
        #media-items .savesend input.button, #gallery-settings * {display:none;}
    </style>';
}
add_action('admin_head', 'auto_media');
```